# Selecting data within a row of a Column

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have table called "lookup" which has a column called "name" which contains a bit of data starting with "Quantity for pricing" (the data I need is in the same cell just after Quantity for Pricing). I was wondering if there was any way to pull out that "row", and list all the quantities except for Quantity for Pricing using mysql?

Sorry for the confusion guys, this is what I am dealing with.
[image]

I am pretty sure the data I need (the actual quantities) are stored in the same bit that "Quantity for Pricing" is.

Comment: How is this data stored in this cell?  Is it comma delimited or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring operation.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,LENGTH('Quantity for pricing'))          
FROM lookup WHERE name LIKE 'Quantity for pricing%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

`SELECT REPLACE(name,"Quantity for pricing","") AS name FROM lookup;`

This selects all of the rows from the table `lookup`, returning the value in column `name`, but excluding the occurence of "Quantity for pricing" in the column value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE

```
SELECT REPLACE(columnToSearch, 'Quantity for pricing ', '') FROM TableToSearch;
```